# array in jquery: How to check if an element exists in an array

Tags: jquery

Please can you help me in this issue? I don't know where is the problem in this code.

I have a main array named LookUp.AppSubCategoryList.
I created two arrays, obj and App.
In the first I put all Applications existing in AppSubCategoryList.
NOTE (Application: ApplicationId, ApplicationName, CreatedAt, CreatedBy)
In the second list I want to filter these Applications by Id (There is already Applications with same Id)

```
     function loadApplicationList() {
        var obj = [], App = [];
// put all Application in the obj array
        $.each(LookUp.AppSubCategoryList, function (i, data) {
            obj.push(data.Application);
        });
// trying to put distinct( Application) in the App array.
        $.each(obj, function (i, data) {
            if ($.inArray(data.ApplicationId, App) == -1)
            {
                App.push(data);
            }
        });
        $('#ApplicationLst').empty();

        Utilities.LoadDropDown($('#ApplicationLst'), App, 'ApplicationId', 'ApplicationName', '', '', '', true);
    }
```

In the result I have always All Application in App!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
var id="id_to_be_filtered";
App = jQuery.grep(obj, function( data ) {
  return data.ApplicationId == id;
});
```

you can use Jquery grep function for filtering, hope this wil help you